# How to run "&" operation sequentially

Tags: shell-script, ksh, background-process, concurrency

From my script I am running following commands:

```
 SCRIPT_1="ksh -x script1.sh & ksh -x script2.sh";
 SCRIPT_2="ksh -x script3.sh & ksh -x script4.sh";
 eval $SCRIPT_1;
 sleep 20s;
 eval $SCRIPT_2;
```

I want to only execute the `$SCRIPT_2` after the `$SCRIPT_1` completes. But currently they both getting executed at the same time regardless of they are being executed in separate lines.

Any idea on how to wait for the other script to finish before executing the next one?

Comment: Just use `wait` to wait for all the background jobs.

Comment: See `help wait`.

Comment: That code runs `script1.sh` in the background but `script2.sh` in the foreground. Is that intended? The scripts of `$SCRIPT_1` shall run in parallel and after all of them have finished those of `$SCRIPT_2` shall run in parallel?

Comment: @HaukeLaging yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SCRIPT_1="ksh -x script1.sh & bg_pid=$!; ksh -x script2.sh; wait $bg_pid";
SCRIPT_2="ksh -x script3.sh & bg_pid=$!; ksh -x script4.sh; wait $bg_pid";
eval $SCRIPT_1;
sleep 20s;
eval $SCRIPT_2;
```

Comment: guess I wasn't clear. My problem is that I need to run String "$SCRIPT_1" first using eval command and then run the String "$SCRIPT_2" sequentially.

Comment: Can't you use `ps` to check script is still in process? I'm not sure using ksh, but in bash, I guess you can use: `if [[ $(ps auxww | grep -i "script1.sh" | wc -l) -gt 1 ]] || [[ $(ps auxww | grep -i "script2.sh" | wc -l) -gt 1 ]]; then echo "Still in process "; else echo "Process SCRIPT_1 ended" ; fi;` Maybe you should adapt it to ksh. Not sure.

Comment: @Albert You should rather use `jobs` (in `bash`; I am not familiar with `ksh`) for checking for background jobs. But `wait` is the superior approach anyway.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I'm quite sure. `ps` is the only way I knew to check if a process is running. Did not even know commands can be run using `&` concatenated. Not even the meaning of "$!". Now I know (after goggling... xD)

Comment: @Albert In the general case it is faster to just check whether `/proc/$PID` exists: `if [ -d /proc/12345 ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi`

Comment: @HaukeLaging. Until now did not know any other way to get the PID than use `ps`. So I used to run `ps | grep "command"`. From now on, I'll try to remember `$!`

Comment: Don't need to be so complicated: `ksh -x script1.sh & ksh -x script2.sh; wait` is enough.

Comment: @Scott Whether that is enough depends on the situation. My solution avoids problems that can arise with your code.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Such as?

Comment: @Scott Such as having other background processes running before these commands are executed.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel you would do something like:

```
parallel ksh -x ::: script1.sh script2.sh
parallel ksh -x ::: script3.sh script4.sh
```